# Spark Dataframe performance for overwrite

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any performance difference or considerations between the following two pyspark statements:

```
df5 = df5.drop("Ratings")
```

and

```
df6 = df5.drop("Ratings)
```

Not specifically targeting the drop function, but any operation.  Was wondering what happens under the hood when you overwrite a variable compared to creating a new one.

Also, is the behavior and performance considerations the same if this was an RDD and not a dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, There won't be any difference in the operation.**

In case of Numpy, There is a option of flag which shows whether its own the data or not.

```
variable_name.flag
```

In case of Pyspark, the Dataframe is immutable and every change in the dataframe creates a new Dataframe. How does it do ? well, Dataframe is stored in distributed fashion. So, to move data in memory costs. Therefore, they change the ownership of data from a Dataframe to another, more particularly where index of the data is stored.

and
Dataframe is way better than RDD. Here is a good blog.
[Dataframe RDD and dataset](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html)